# Access data in fastest way, objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, plist

in my iphone application i've a Xml file downloaded from a server which contains 20-30 strings. In the app i want to access particular nodes, the user insert two numbers and i want the corrispondent strings.

Is more performant access each time the XML file and scroll node until i reach the two indices entered by user or is it better convert the Xml file into a PLIST and then, import PLIST into an array and access data by it?

Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how often you intend to access it, really. An alternative to the plist is to simply parse the XML and store the data on the phone at startup or whenever the XML file is downloaded. That way even if your users access it repeatedly you'll only actually go through it one time.